# Converting epochtime to localtime zone(with Microseconds)

Tags: powershell, epoch

When I use Get-EpochDate time just shows only in second(Thursday, August 15, 2019 4:07:09 PM).Below is the code i'M using

```
Function Get-EpochDate ($epochDate) { [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddMilliSeconds($epochDate)) }

 get-EpochDate 1565899629580 / 1000000
```

I'm expecting it to be:

`Thursday, August 15, 2019 4:07:09.580 PM`

Comment: Theen don't use the default format. The milliseconds ***are*** there `(get-EpochDate 1565899629580 / 1000000).millisecond` returns 580 here.

Comment: Retuns only 580. I need time to DateandTime to be this format: ```Thursday, August 15, 2019 4:07:09.580 PM```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default format doesn't output milliseconds, even though they are there.

Remember that the internal [datetime] representation and the output format are different things.

Once you apply a format, it's no longer a datetime but a string.

As my locale/CultureInfo doesn't support AM/PM, I have to specify it explicitly here:

```
$CIUS = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo en-US
(Get-EpochDate 1565899629580).ToString('dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt zzzz', $CIUS)
```

I added the time zone to show my offset in the output I get here:

```
Thursday, August 15, 2019 10:07:09.580 PM +02:00
```

Comment: Probably the only answer viable. As stated, the `[timezone]` and `[datetime]` objects don't output the ms so you will need to output it as a string rather than an object.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [LotPings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813957/45375):

```
get-EpochDate 1565899629580 / 1000000
```

doesn't do what you might expect (even though it happens to give the right result); it is effectively the same as:

```
get-EpochDate 1565899629580
```

That is, `/` and `1000000` are passed as *separate arguments* and - because your function declares only *one* parameter - are *ignored*.

If you really want to pass the result of *expression* `1565899629580 / 1000000` to `get-EpochDate`, you'll have to enclose it *in parentheses* (`(...)`):

```
get-EpochDate (1565899629580 / 1000000)
```

If, by contrast, you want to perform the division on the *result* of your `get-EpochDate` call, put the call into parentheses, but note that this won't work in your particular case due to the data types involved:

```
# Correct syntax, but since get-EpochData returns a [datetime] instance,
# you cannot directly apply division (/) to it.
(get-EpochDate 1565899629580) / 1000000
```

---

You could have caught the problem with the ignored arguments if you had declared your function as an [*advanced* (cmdlet-like) function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced), because such functions report an error if unexpected arguments are passed; also, advanced functions can mark parameters as *mandatory*.

Also, you can simplify `[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime([datetime]'1/1/1970')` to `[datetime] '1970-01-01Z'`.

The following definition shows both improvements:

```
Function Get-EpochDate {
  [CmdletBinding()] # Make the function advanced so that it only accepts declared parameters.
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] # Mark the parameter as mandatory.
    [long] $epochDateMs
  )
  ([datetime] '1970-01-01Z').AddMilliSeconds($epochDateMs)
}
```

The function outputs a local `[datetime]` instance (`.Kind` is `Local`).

To format it with milliseconds, you need to use `.ToString()` with an explicit format string, as shown in LotPings' answer.